# How to find the minimum value of an array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, mips, cpu-registers

here is my code, I am having trouble getting the correct output. Where am I going wrong?I set min originally to zero, then check if the array is less than or equal to this value and then if it is I jump to a label and make the value of min to be the value of the array, then jump back to iterating the array.

```
xyz:    .word   -8, 16, -32, 64, -128, 256 

# int main(void)
#
# local variable    register
#   int *p      $s0
#   int *end    $s1
#   int min     $s2  
#   int total   $s3
#   
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    la  $s0, xyz                # p = foo
    addi    $s1, $s0, 24        # end = p + 6
    add $s3, $zero, $zero       # total = 0 
    add     $s2, $zero, $zero   # min = 0
L1:
    beq $s0, $s1, L2    # if (p == end) goto L2
    lw  $t0, ($s0)      # $t0 = *p
    lw  $t1, ($s2)      # $t1 = min
    slt $t2, $t1, $t0       # check if min is less than p
    add $s3, $s3, $t0       # total += $t0
    bne     $t2, $zero, L3      # if min is less than p, go to L3 
    addi    $s0, $s0, 4     # p++
    j   L1
L2:     
    add $v0, $zero, $zero   # return value from main = 0
    jr  $ra

L3:
    move    $s2, $t0
    j   L1
```

Comment: Why are you programming in assembly?

Comment: Your title says you want the min value of the array, but your code is structured to get the max value [along with some bugs]. Which value do you want (min=-128 or max=256)?

Comment: ohhh, I am trying to get the min. What did I do to get the max instead of min?

Comment: I've been prepping an answer, which I'll post soon that will annotate such things [and the 4 other bugs I found] and I'll provide a fixed version. However, a simple `slt` doesn't handle negative numbers too well because it treats the numbers as unsigned. Are you required to do negative values?

Comment: yes, negatives are vital as I need to learn how to treat them in MIPS. so you are saying that slt is treating -128 as 128 ?

Comment: Oops, my bad. `slt` _is_ the signed version [there is an `sltu` for unsigned]. I'm just not [yet] getting the expected result, so keep your fingers crossed ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I found several bugs. I've created three versions and I added output syscalls so you can see results [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

---

Here is your original code with annotations for the bugs:

```
    .data
xyz:        .word       -8,16,-32,64,-128,256

# int main(void)
#
# local variable    register
#   int *p      $s0
#   int *end    $s1
#   int min     $s2
#   int total   $s3
#
    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    la      $s0,xyz                 # p = foo
    addi    $s1,$s0,24              # end = p + 6
    add     $s3,$zero,$zero         # total = 0

    # NOTE/BUG: to find minimum, you want to init this to the first array
    # element
    # also, initializing with a minimum value (e.g. 0), or more correctly, the
    # largest possible negative number (e.g. 0x80000000) implies a search for
    # maximum
    add     $s2,$zero,$zero         # min = 0

L1:
    beq     $s0,$s1,L2              # if (p == end) goto L2
    lw      $t0,($s0)               # $t0 = *p

    # NOTE/BUG: s2 is a register variable that contains "min" (e.g. int min)
    # and is _not_ a pointer to a "min" variable in memory (e.g. int *min)
    lw      $t1,($s2)               # $t1 = min

    # NOTE/BUG: the the check should be reversed:
    slt     $t2,$t1,$t0             # check if min is less than p
    add     $s3,$s3,$t0             # total += $t0

    bne     $t2,$zero,L3            # if min is less than p, go to L3

    # NOTE/BUG: this pointer increment is out of place (i.e. it does not
    # get incremented if there is a jump to L3)
    # this won't affect the min value, but it will double count the value in
    # the total
    addi    $s0,$s0,4               # p++
    j       L1

L2:
    add     $v0,$zero,$zero         # return value from main = 0
    jr      $ra

L3:
    move    $s2,$t0
    j       L1
```

---

Here is a fixed version:

```
    .data
xyz:        .word       -8,16,-32,64,-128,256
msg_min:    .asciiz     "min: "
msg_tot:    .asciiz     " total: "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

# int main(void)
#
# local variable    register
#   int *p      $s0
#   int *end    $s1
#   int min     $s2
#   int total   $s3
#
    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    la      $s0,xyz                 # p = foo
    addi    $s1,$s0,24              # end = p + 6
    add     $s3,$zero,$zero         # total = 0

    lw      $s2,0($s0)              # min = xyz[0]

L1:
    beq     $s0,$s1,L2              # if (p == end) goto L2

    lw      $t0,0($s0)              # $t0 = *p
    addi    $s0,$s0,4               # p++

    add     $s3,$s3,$t0             # total += $t0

    slt     $t2,$t0,$s2             # *p < min?
    bne     $t2,$zero,L3            # yes, fly

    j       L1

L2:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_min
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s2                 # get min value
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_tot
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s3                 # get total value
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall

    # exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

L3:
    move    $s2,$t0                 # set new/better min value
    j       L1
```

---

Here is a slightly more cleaned up version where I reversed the sense of a branch and was able to tighten up the loop a bit. Also, I changed the labels to be more descriptive of role/function:

```
    .data
xyz:        .word       -8,16,-32,64,-128,256
msg_min:    .asciiz     "min: "
msg_tot:    .asciiz     " total: "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

# int main(void)
#
# local variable    register
#   int *p      $s0
#   int *end    $s1
#   int min     $s2
#   int total   $s3
#
    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    la      $s0,xyz                 # p = foo
    addi    $s1,$s0,24              # end = p + 6
    add     $s3,$zero,$zero         # total = 0

    lw      $s2,0($s0)              # min = xyz[0]

main_loop:
    beq     $s0,$s1,main_done       # if (p == end) goto L2

    lw      $t0,0($s0)              # $t0 = *p
    addi    $s0,$s0,4               # p++

    add     $s3,$s3,$t0             # total += $t0

    slt     $t2,$s2,$t0             # *p < min?
    bne     $t2,$zero,main_loop     # no, loop

    move    $s2,$t0                 # set new/better min value
    j       main_loop

main_done:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_min
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s2                 # get min value
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_tot
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s3                 # get total value
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall

    # exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> thanks that helped a lot, but `lw $t1,($s2)` doesnt work because lw will only work on pointers?

Right. Notice how you were using `s3` to hold `total`. That's how the code used `s2` to hold min. I did this [partly] because of the top comment:

```
#   int min     $s2
```

To use the `lw`, the top comment should have been:

```
#   int *min    $s2
```

To use `s2` in the original way for this, you'd need something like:

```
min:    .word    0
```

And, you'd need (before the loop start):

```
la    $s2,min
```

And, you'd have to `lw` and `sw` to it, which would only slow things down. So, you'd need to add an extra `lw` and an extra `sw` in addition to what's already there.

mips has a *lot* of registers [its forte]. So, it speeds things up to keep automatic, function scoped variables in them.

However, for completeness, here's a version that allows the `lw` as you were using it. Notice the extra memory accesses. It's a lot like C code compiled with -O0:

```
    .data
min:        .word       0
xyz:        .word       -8,16,-32,64,-128,256
msg_min:    .asciiz     "min: "
msg_tot:    .asciiz     " total: "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"

# int main(void)
#
# local variable    register
#   int *p      $s0
#   int *end    $s1
#   int *min    $s2
#   int total   $s3
#
    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    la      $s0,xyz                 # p = foo
    addi    $s1,$s0,24              # end = p + 6
    add     $s3,$zero,$zero         # total = 0

    la      $s2,min                 # point to min
    lw      $t4,0($s0)              # fetch xyz[0]
    sw      $t4,0($s2)              # store in min

main_loop:
    beq     $s0,$s1,main_done       # if (p == end) goto L2

    lw      $t0,0($s0)              # $t0 = *p
    addi    $s0,$s0,4               # p++

    add     $s3,$s3,$t0             # total += $t0

    lw      $t4,0($s2)              # fetch min
    slt     $t2,$t4,$t0             # *p < min?
    bne     $t2,$zero,main_loop     # no, loop

    sw      $t0,0($s2)              # store new/better min value
    j       main_loop

main_done:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_min
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    lw      $a0,0($s2)              # get min value
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_tot
    syscall

    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$s3                 # get total value
    syscall

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall

    # exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, but lw      $t1,($s2) doesnt work because lw will only work on pointers?